# How to turn off Application Insights performance counters and tracking telemetry in .Net Core 3.1 web app

Tags: .net-core, azure-application-insights

How to turn off Application Insights performance counters and tracking telemetry in .Net Core 3.1 web app ?
I've tried to disable these modules like so:

```
ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions aiOptions = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();

aiOptions.EnablePerformanceCounterCollectionModule = false;
aiOptions.EnableDependencyTrackingTelemetryModule = false;

services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Why don't you just uninstall the AI NuGet packages?

Comment: Because I want them to be turned off only on the staging environment.

Comment: Your code seems to be doing the correct thing. How did you confirm that it is not working?

Comment: Because there are still performance counters in AI app after redeployment.